# enclosing environment never changes?

Tags: r

quoted from Hadley's book [advanced R: Environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)

> The enclosing environment belongs to the function, and never changes, even if the function is moved to a different environment.

the following code shows the enclosing environment of `f` is modified to be environment `e`. So what does it mean exactly by saying 'enclosing environment does not change'?

```
f = function() { }   
environment(f) # <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
e = new.env()        
environment(f) = e   
environment(f) #  <environment: 0x2a01c88>
```

Comment: `e$f()` evalutes to 2 because  `environment(e$f)` is still `globalenv()`. maybe I overread the quoted statement from Hadley? enclosing environment can definitely change if you modify it.

Comment: I edited the scroll bars away. I hate those things :).