# Environment issues in R

Tags: r, environment

Just to clarify, I'm not saying that R has issues. The problem is probably on my side, but I'm really confused. I have a function (`make_a()`) that creates a function `a()`. I also have a function that uses this function in its definition (`fun_using_a()`):

```
make_a <- function(x) {
  a <- function(y) {
   x + y
  }
  a
}

fun_using_a <- function(x) {
  a(x)/2
}
```

Now, I create another function that uses these two:

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  a <- make_a(1)
  fun_using_a(x)
}
```

Calling `my_fun(10)` gives an error:

```
my_fun(10)
```

Error in a(x) : could not find function "a"

However, everything works fine if do essentially the same thing in the global environment:

```
a <- make_a(1)
fun_using_a(10)
```

[1] 5.5

What's going on here? Why does `my_fun(10)` throw an error? It seems that my understanding of R environments must be a bit off somewhere, but I just can't figure it out. When I call `my_fun()`, shouldn't the function `a()` be defined in the execution environment after the first line and thus `fun_using_a()` should be able to find it there (due to lazy evaluation)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The behavior is expected. If R doesn't find an object in the local environment, it looks in the enclosing environment, i.e., the environment where the function was originally created. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441912/1315472 and http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to save the result of `make_a` with name `a` in a place where `fun_using_a` can see it.  There isn't a single "execution environment", every function invocation creates a new one.  As posted, `make_a` returns a function, but you didn't show it being saved anywhere until your second version of the code.

By the way, `make_a` is likely to have a subtle bug:  since `x` is never evaluated until the first call to `a()`, its value could change.  For example,

```
x <- 1
a <- make_a(x)
x <- 5
fun_using_a(10)
```

will return 7.5, not 5.5, since the value of `x` in `a(y)` will be 5 instead of 1.  To fix it, force the value of `x` in `make_a`:

```
make_a_2 <- function(x) {
  force(x)
  a <- function(y) {
   x + y
  }
  a
}
```